# Rename the superposition theorem tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag named [superpositiontheorem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superpositiontheorem) which is currently on 12 questions. Tags composed of multiple words generally use hyphens between the words by [convention](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> #### How to format tags
>
> - Use all lower case
> - Replace spaces with hyphens (-) to combine multiple words into a single word (e.g., tag "unit testing" as `unit-testing`)
>
>   ...

Can we rename this tag to [superposition-theorem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superposition-theorem) or perhaps just [superposition](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superposition)? Since it's only on a few questions it won't take much effort to rename it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like there's good support for this, go ahead and name it [superposition](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superposition).

Comment: All the questions have been retagged.

Comment: @Null Thanks for doing that and the tag wiki